# git checkout/reset commit_hash with link

Tags: git, github

For example next path:

```
https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/7245bff300d3fa8bacbef7897ff080a6f1c23eba?w=1
```

```
git clone https://github.com/php-src/php-src.git

git reset --hard 7245bff300d3fa8bacbef7897ff080a6f1c23eba?w=1

fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.
```

Same problem for checkout

How can I do `git reset` with `commit_hash(7245bff300d3fa8bacbef7897ff080a6f1c23eba)` with `link=?w=1`

Comment: `?w=1` is a query string of an HTTP URL. It has nothing to do with Git and is not part of the commit hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `git reset --hard` to a file, only to a commit:

```
git reset --hard 7245bff300d3fa8bacbef7897ff080a6f1c23eba
```

You can checkout a single file from a commit to the current worktree:

```
git checkout 7245bff300d3fa8bacbef7897ff080a6f1c23eba ext/spl/spl_directory.c
```

Comment: This isn't that relevant to this question, but it may be worth adding that `reset --hard`  is very happy with other references like `HEAD`, e.g. `git reset --hard HEAD~3`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `git checkout [commit] <paths>`.

This is covered in the official [7.7 Git Tools - Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) under 'Check It Out'.

> ### Check It Out
>
> Finally, you may wonder what the difference between checkout and reset is. Like reset, checkout manipulates the three trees, and it is a bit different depending on whether you give the command a file path or not.
>
> ...
>
> #### With Paths
>
> The other way to run `checkout` is with a file path, which, like reset, does not move HEAD. It is just like `git reset [branch] file` in that it updates the index with that file at that commit, but it also overwrites the file in the working directory. It would be exactly like `git reset --hard [branch] file` (if reset would let you run that) — it’s not working-directory safe, and it does not move HEAD.

In the summary, there is a cheat-sheet, shown below.

Please note there is **no** row for row with `git reset --hard [branch] file`.

> Here’s a cheat-sheet for which commands affect which trees. The “HEAD” column reads “REF” if that command moves the reference (branch) that HEAD points to, and “HEAD” if it moves HEAD itself. Pay especial attention to the 'WD Safe?' column — if it says **NO**, take a second to think before running that command.
>
> |  | HEAD | Index | Workdir | WD Safe? |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Commit Level |  |  |  |  |
> | reset --soft [commit] | REF | NO | NO | YES |
> | reset [commit] | REF | YES | NO | YES |
> | reset --hard [commit] | REF | YES | YES | **NO** |
> | checkout <commit> | HEAD | YES | YES | YES |
> | File Level |  |  |  |  |
> | reset [commit] <paths> | NO | YES | NO | YES |
> | checkout [commit] <paths> | NO | YES | YES | **NO** |